# systemsettings is missing in KDE

Tags: 14.04, kde

after removing some desktop environments, I face this strange problem: in KDE, systemsettings is completely missing (take a look at screenshot).

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reinstalling KDE, everything is fine

```
 sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```